# factor 2pi in golden rule

Tags: fermis-golden-rule

For the Golden Rule cross-section function, there is a factor $2pi$ in every delta function and a factor of $1/2pi$ for every derivative.
Any easy and intuitive way to understand such factors?

Comment: Hint: it's all because the inverse of the Fourier transform $\tilde{f}(k)=\int_{\Bbb R^n}f(x)e^{-ik\cdot x}d^nx$ is $f(x)=(2\pi)^{-n}\int_{\Bbb R^n}\tilde{f}(k)e^{ik\cdot x}d^nk$.

Comment: Many thank!
But what about the $2\pi$ for each delta function?

Comment: Well, that the inverse works that way is equivalent to $\int_{\Bbb R^n}e^{ik\cdot x}d^nx=(2\pi)^n\delta^n(k)$.